# cannot emplicity covert type decimal to string

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm tring to call a stored procedure into a ActionResult from the view model.

input variable nGUID is a string, both KeepPersonID and dropPersonID are of type decimal.  When I tried to run my code I get an error **'Cannot implicitly convert type decimal to string'**
Here is my code.

**Called Procedure MergeAuthIDs**

```
public static void MergeAuthIDs(
OracleTransaction trans, decimal KeepPersonID, decimal dropPersonID)
{
  using (OracleCommand cm = new OracleCommand())
   {
     cm.Connection = trans.Connection;
     cm.Transaction = trans;
     cm.CommandText = "TheService.PKG#IDENTITIES.Merge_Auth_Ids";
     cm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
     cm.AddToStatementCache = true;

     OracleParameter param = cm.Paramaters.Add("P_KEEP_PERSON_ID", OracleDBType.Decimal, Paremeter.Direction.Input);
     param.Value = keepPersonID;

     param = cm.Paramaters.Add("P_DROP_PERSON_ID", OracleDBType.Decimal, Paremeter.Direction.Input);
     param.Value = dropPersonID;

     cm.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

**IdentityConfirmed ViewModel Controller**

```
[httpPost]
public ActionResult IdentityConfirmed(FormCollection collection)
{
    Guid request = new Guid(collection["ciGUID"]);

    dsSession.SECURE_REQUESTSRow secureRequest;

    using (OracleConnection cn = new OracleConnection (OracleConnectionManager.GetProxyServiceConnetionString()))
    {
        cn.Open();
        using (OracleTransaction trans = cn.BeginTransaction())
        {
              using (Data.dsSessionTableAdapters.SECURE_REQUESTSTableAdapter ta = new Data.dsSessionTableAdapters.SECURE_REQUESTSTableAdapter();
              {
                 typedDatasetFiller.ApplyConnection(ta, cn);
                 secureRequest = ta.GetDataBySecureGUID(request.ToByteArray())[0];
              }
              decimal KeepPersonID = SessionManager.PersonIdentity.PERSON_ID;
              decimal dropPersonID = secureRequest.REQUESTER_PERSON_ID;

              Support.MergeAuthIDs(trans, KeepPersonID, dropPersonID);
              trans.Commit();
        }
    }
retrun View("IdentityConfirmed", vm);
}
```

Comment: Where do you get the error?

Comment: I get the error at Convert.ToDecimal(nGUID).

Comment: Is there a way I can convert string to decimal?

Comment: That line cannot give that error.

Comment: I put a break on decimal KeepPersonID = Convert.ToDecimal(nGUID); The actual error I get is Input string was not in correct format.

Comment: That means that your string isn't a number.

Comment: I know that is why I was trying to convert it to a decimal, Is it a way I can convert a string to decimal?

Comment: What decimal do you want to get?  You cannot convert the string `"abc"` into a decimal.

Answer (score 0):

It expects that to be a string. Check your column type in database and change it to decimal.

Comment: The input string is from a form and passed to the ViewModel nGUID.

Comment: But it is trying to convert a decimal to a string?

Comment: on this line decimal KeepPersonID = Convert.ToDecimal(nGUID);

Comment: collection["nGUID"] does this one really work? Because it should be a form, not a string.

Comment: It is coming from a form. nGUID is passing the data

Answer (score 0):

here is the answer, I forgot to set the variable dropPersonID to the right value.

```
     using (Data.dsSessionTableAdapters.SECURE_REQUESTSTableAdapter ta = new  Data.dsSessionTableAdapters.SECURE_REQUESTSTableAdapter();
          {
             typedDatasetFiller.ApplyConnection(ta, cn);
             secureRequest = ta.GetDataBySecureGUID(request.ToByteArray())[0];
          }
          decimal KeepPersonID = SessionManager.PersonIdentity.PERSON_ID;
          decimal dropPersonID = secureRequest.REQUESTER_PERSON_ID;

          Support.MergeAuthIDs(trans, KeepPersonID, dropPersonID);
```